# How to sort items in a list by the frequency of it in descending order in dart?

Tags: list, dart

Lets say I have list `l=[a,b,c,d,a,s,b,d,c,r,s,r,r,s,w,c,r]`

So the number of time of Occurrence of a=2,b=2,c=3,d=2,s=3,r=4,w=1

So the final result should be list `l=[r,s,c,a,b,d,w]`

because r was repeated most number of times,
s was repeated the most number of times but less that r and so on. It should be in descending order of their frequency

Comment: What are the rules if a letter does appear the same number of times? Are there any specific order you want in this case?

Comment: No it doesnt matter if it letter does appear the same number of times

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use the following code if you want a compact way to do it:

```
void main() {
  final input = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 's', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'r', 's', 'r', 'r', 's', 'w', 'c', 'r'];
  print(itemsByFrequency(input)); // [r, c, s, a, b, d, w]
}

List<String> itemsByFrequency(List<String> input) => [
      ...(input
              .fold<Map<String, int>>(
                  <String, int>{},
                  (map, letter) => map
                    ..update(letter, (value) => value + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1))
              .entries
              .toList()
                ..sort((e1, e2) => e2.value.compareTo(e1.value)))
          .map((e) => e.key)
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collection` module, for the sorting in the map

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  List<String> l=['a','b','c','d','a','s','b','d','c','r','s','r','r','s','w','c','r'];
  
  //maintaing the map to keep the count of the item
  Map item = {};
  
  // adding the count of the item
  l.forEach((e){
    // if item key is there, then +1
    if(item.containsKey(e)) item[e] += 1;
    else item[e] = 1;
  });
  
  // sorting the item based on decreasing order
  var sortedKeys = item.keys.toList(growable:false)
    ..sort((k1, k2) => item[k2].compareTo(item[k1]));
  LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap
      .fromIterable(sortedKeys, key: (k) => k, value: (k) => item[k]);
  
  // this will contain the keys from sortedMap
  List myList = [];
  sortedMap.forEach((k,v){
    myList.add(k);
  });
  
  print(myList);
}
```

**Output**

```
[r, c, s, a, b, d, w]
```